# error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type when incrementally filling in vectors

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am trying to fill arrays starting at initial values (location in xyz space) and move forward in the space by a discrete step to fill a 3d box.

I can't find a solution to this error message applied to something similar anywhere. Most of the answers to similar question involve some sort of syntax error. Maybe mine is too, I am still relatively new to C and C++.

I have tried casting i to an int while indexing into x_array and it just throws any even more cryptic error:

```
error: no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>> = float
```

Here is my code:

```
atom_box build_box(
          vector<xyz_coords> all_atom_coords, vector<string> all_atom_names, vector<float> box_origin_coords,
          map<string, float> p_charge_map, map <string, float> solv_access_map,
          int box_size = 20, const int channels = 7, float voxel = 1.0)
{
  float x1,x2, y1,y2, z1,z2; // first and last values of the box
  const int  x_dim = box_size, y_dim = box_size, z_dim = box_size;
  atom_box box(channels, x_dim, y_dim, z_dim);
  map<char,int> atom_chann_map = {  {'N', 0}, {'C', 1}, {'O', 2}, {'S', 3}, {'H', 4}  };

  float delta =  box_size/2.0;
  //cout << "Delta: " << delta << endl;

  x1 = box_origin_coords[0] - delta; x2 = box_origin_coords[0] + delta;
  y1 = box_origin_coords[1] - delta; y2 = box_origin_coords[1] + delta;
  z1 = box_origin_coords[2] - delta; z2 = box_origin_coords[2] + delta;

  int size = (x2 - x1)/voxel + 1;
  vector<float> x_range[size], y_range[size], z_range[size];

  for (float i = 0, x = x1, y = y1, z = z1;
       i < size;
       i++, x += voxel, y += voxel, z += voxel)
  {
    x_range[i] = x; y_range[i] = y; z_range[i] = z;
  }

  return box;
}
```

Comment: I  imagine these are typos: `vector<float> x_range[size], y_range[size], z_range[size];`. You need `vector<float> x_range(size), y_range(size), z_range(size);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from this line:

```
vector<float> x_range[size], y_range[size], z_range[size];
```

`vector<float> x_range[size]` declares an **array of** vectors, instead of a single vector, due to the square brackets `[]`. Unfortunately, since `size` is not a compile-time constant, this is non-standard behavior, called Variable-Length Arrays, and your compiler is allowing it only as a quirk.

Due to this, every `x_range[i]` is *itself* a `vector<float>`, and not simply a `float`.

You probably want  `vector<float> x_range(size);`, which declares a single vector with a specific size.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I had no idea. I really appreciate your help!!! Ive been trying to fixe it for 2 hours.